# RabbitMQ client with SSL connection throws SSPI exception

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, rabbitmq, sspi

When using the RabbitMQ client with SSL enabled, `CreateConnection();` throws an exception.

The inner exception is with SSPI and inside that a token invalid exception.

The RabbitMQ server has been tested in java and works as expected, so the problem must lie in the .Net security library.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

C# code:

```
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.HostName = "hostname";
    factory.Port = 5671;
    factory.UserName = "username";
    factory.Password = "password";
    factory.Ssl.Enabled = true;

    var conn = factory.CreateConnection();
```

Exception:

```
"RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The token supplied to the function is invalid\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceive



Blob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at Sy 

stem.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncPro 

tocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevoc 

ation)\r\n   at RabbitMQ.Client.SslHelper.TcpUpgrade(Stream tcpStream, SslOption sslOption)\r\n   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, ObtainSocket socketFactory, Int32 timeout)\r\n   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.ProtocolBase.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, ObtainSocket socketFactory, Int32 timeout)\r\n   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler()\r\n   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()\r\n   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in \\\\vmware-host\\shared folders\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1\\Program.cs:line 50"
```

java code:

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("host");
    factory.setPort(5671);
    factory.setUsername("username");
    factory.setPassword("password");
    factory.useSslProtocol();

    Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same issue and it took hours to work out what was going on. It actually wasn't anything to do with the .Net client directly even though the Java client working made us believe it was.

Our main issue was caused by the version of Erlang that comes with the Ubuntu image on AWS.(Erlang R16B03). We updated to Erlang version 17.4 and it started working! :)

There's a little more information on this erlang bug [here](http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/RabbitMQ-3-2-2-and-Erlang-R16B03-SSL-Issue-td32726.html).